# how to concatenate in a countif in excel

Tags: excel, concatenation

I am trying to search through a table and concatenate the cells that meat a criteria from another column.  In the example below I would like to say if(C = c1)  concatenate A, concatenate the Names in colum A and put them in ""

```
  A      B   C

Name 1  P1  C1
Name 2  P2  C1
Name 3  P1  C2
Name 4  P1  C2
```

The result should look like this

```
C2 = "Name 3" "Name 4"
```

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service.  Please try to write the code yourself and if you then run into errors or problems you can then post them here and the community will help you solve that.

Comment: Is column C always sorted?  Are there always 2 that should be concatenated?  If the answer to either of those questions is no then you will need vba and as @BearArmatis just commented SO is not a code for me site.

Comment: No column C is not sorted.  It is also a list of 6000 or so.  I will have to look into the VBA.  I figured this could be done in simple excel formulas, which is why i didn't write any code.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Dim row as Integer
row = 2
While Sheets(1).Range("C" + Cstr(row)).value <> ""
    If Sheets(1).Range("C" + Cstr(row)).value = Sheets(1).Range("C" + Cstr(row+1)).Value Then
        Sheets(1).Range("D" + Cstr(row)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A" + Cstr(row)).Value + " " + Sheets(1).Range("A" + Cstr(row+1)).Value
    End If
    row = row + 1
Wend
```

Or if you want a cell formula, put this in the cell D2 and then drag down:

```
=IF(C1=C2,A1 & " " & A2,"")
```

If you want to sort using VBA modifying this code will do it. You'll want to change the ranges and the keys, and this one has two sort keys.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Range("A1:M" + Trim(Str(RowCount)))
    .Sort Key1:=Range("M1"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, _
          Header:=xlYes, _
          MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    .Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, _
          Header:=xlYes, _
          MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: This'll have to be modified to add the double quotes, but you get the idea.

Comment: As the OP stated in the comments, column C will not be sorted.  This method requires that column C is sorted.   You are also overwriting the very cells you are testing. thus if there are more than two with the same value in column C it will only grab every two.

Comment: I was writing as the comments came so I didn't see them until I'd finished, and yeah, I should've put column D like I did in the cell, but you know something y'all be very free with the down ticks. I'll remember that.

Comment: First, I did not down vote you, my comment was not meant as criticism but as items that I saw that were in error that would give you the opportunity to fix. I, in fact, have code that does what is wanted but I wanted to give you time to fix the issues. Second if I were to guess as to why you were down voted I would guess that it had more to do with the fact that the forum is very anti doing the work for someone.  The rule I use if it is a unique puzzle or the OP shows effort I help, otherwise risk being down voted, and I have been many times because the forum felt I broke the unwritten rule.

Comment: My apology, we obviously have people who will down vote but have no desire to offer solutions. I dislike the down votes, I don't feel they accomplish anything and they discourage people from trying to help. Maybe they should add that to the written rules then. It's hard to know an unwritten rule, if it is, well unwritten.

Comment: Your solution still only works for two.  I know the OP did not answer that question if there are more or not, but I would assume so with 6000 rows.  One thing I have noticed is that the OPs does not always state every contingency, and we need to sometimes go fishing for information.  Or, we can simply make sure the code works for any contingency.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I didn't realize I was going to create such a problem :-(